# Why is my video rotating when I add a watermark?

Tags: swift, calayer, avassetexportsession, avmutablecomposition

I am cropping a video using `AVAssetExportSession` and having no problems:

```
func cropVideo() {

        let videoAsset = AVAsset(URL: recordedVideoURL)

        let mixComposition = AVMutableComposition()

        do {

            let videoTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))


            //First 5 seconds
            try videoTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, CMTimeMake(5, 1)), ofTrack: videoAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)[0], atTime: kCMTimeZero)

            //Middle 5 seconds
            let middleStart = CMTimeMake(Int64(gameTime/2), 1)
            let middleEnd = CMTimeMake(Int64(((gameTime/2) + 5)), 1)
            try videoTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(middleStart, middleEnd), ofTrack: videoAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)[0], atTime: CMTimeMake(5,1))

            //Last 5 seconds
            let endStart = CMTimeMake(Int64(gameTime-5), 1)
            let endEnd = CMTimeMake(Int64(gameTime), 1)
            try videoTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(endStart, endEnd), ofTrack: videoAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)[0], atTime: CMTimeMake(10,1))


        } catch {
            print(error)
        }

        let assetVideoTrack = videoAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo).last!

        let compositionVideoTrack = mixComposition.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo).last!

        compositionVideoTrack.preferredTransform = assetVideoTrack.preferredTransform

        let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: mixComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)
        deleteFileAtURL(recordedVideoURL)
        exporter!.outputURL = recordedVideoURL
        exporter!.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4
        exporter!.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true

        let startTime = CMTime(seconds: Double(0), preferredTimescale: 1000)
        let endTime = CMTime(seconds: Double(15), preferredTimescale: 1000)
        let timeRange = CMTimeRange(start: startTime, end: endTime)

        exporter!.timeRange = timeRange

        exporter!.exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler() {

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                print("done exporting video")

                self.videoOutlet.enabled = true
                self.videoOutlet.setTitle("Save Video", forState: .Normal)

            })

        }

    }
```

I also need to add a watermark, and when I do that, the watermark is where it should be (along the bottom of the screen) but the video is rotated 90 degrees:

```
func cropVideo() {

    let videoAsset = AVAsset(URL: recordedVideoURL)

    let mixComposition = AVMutableComposition()

    do {

        let videoTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))


        //First 5 seconds
        try videoTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, CMTimeMake(5, 1)), ofTrack: videoAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)[0], atTime: kCMTimeZero)

        //Middle 5 seconds
        let middleStart = CMTimeMake(Int64(gameTime/2), 1)
        let middleEnd = CMTimeMake(Int64(((gameTime/2) + 5)), 1)
        try videoTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(middleStart, middleEnd), ofTrack: videoAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)[0], atTime: CMTimeMake(5,1))

        //Last 5 seconds
        let endStart = CMTimeMake(Int64(gameTime-5), 1)
        let endEnd = CMTimeMake(Int64(gameTime), 1)
        try videoTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(endStart, endEnd), ofTrack: videoAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)[0], atTime: CMTimeMake(10,1))


    } catch {
        print(error)
    }

    let assetVideoTrack = videoAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo).last!

    let compositionVideoTrack = mixComposition.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo).last!

    // Watermark Effect
    let size = mixComposition.naturalSize

    // create text Layer
    let titleLayer = CATextLayer()
    titleLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    titleLayer.string = "Dummy text"
    titleLayer.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 28)
    titleLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    titleLayer.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentCenter
    titleLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 50, size.width, size.height / 6)

    let videolayer = CALayer()
    videolayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)

    let parentlayer = CALayer()
    parentlayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)
    parentlayer.addSublayer(videolayer)
    parentlayer.addSublayer(titleLayer)

    let layercomposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
    layercomposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30)
    layercomposition.renderSize = size
    layercomposition.animationTool = AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool(postProcessingAsVideoLayer: videolayer, inLayer: parentlayer)

    // instruction for watermark
    let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
    instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, mixComposition.duration)

    let layerinstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: compositionVideoTrack)
    instruction.layerInstructions = NSArray(object: layerinstruction) as! [AVVideoCompositionLayerInstruction]
    layercomposition.instructions = NSArray(object: instruction) as! [AVVideoCompositionInstructionProtocol]

    compositionVideoTrack.preferredTransform = assetVideoTrack.preferredTransform

    let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: mixComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)
    deleteFileAtURL(recordedVideoURL)
    exporter!.outputURL = recordedVideoURL
    exporter!.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4
    exporter!.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true

    let startTime = CMTime(seconds: Double(0), preferredTimescale: 1000)
    let endTime = CMTime(seconds: Double(15), preferredTimescale: 1000)
    let timeRange = CMTimeRange(start: startTime, end: endTime)

    exporter!.timeRange = timeRange

    exporter!.videoComposition = layercomposition

    exporter!.exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler() {

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            print("done exporting video")

            self.videoOutlet.enabled = true
            self.videoOutlet.setTitle("Save Video", forState: .Normal)

        })

    }

}
```

What is causing this?

Comment: What are the dimensions of the source, the crop, and the watermark?  (Had an odd thought that the source might be rotated to match the aspect of the watermark ...)

Comment: The source video is shot in full screen on iPhone in portrait mode. Adding the watermark causes it to rotate to landscape.